# Exception not catching when using Custom Exception classes in ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created few custom exception class

```
public class CreateNewUserWebException : Exception
{
    public CreateNewUserWebException(string email): base(
        string.Format("[{0}] - User could not be added.", email))
    {
    }
}
public class CreateNewUserEntityFrameworkException : System.Data.DataException
{
    public CreateNewUserEntityFrameworkException(string email)
        : base(
            string.Format("[{0}] - User could not be added.", email))
    {
    }
}
```

and here is my controller code

```
try
{
    var user = _createUserModule.CreateUser(model);
    CookieManager.SetAuthenticationCookie(user, model.Email, rememberMe: false);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bugs");
}
catch (CreateNewUserEntityFrameworkException exception)
{
    this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some error occured while registering you on our sytem. Please try again later.");
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
}
catch (CreateNewUserWebException exception)
{
    this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some error occured while registering you on our sytem. Please try again later.");
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some error occured while registering you on our sytem. Please try again later.");
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
}
```

I have purposely fully induced an primary key violation exception which is

[image]

but exception is not catched by my custom exception class. It is not caught by the last exception catch block.

I cannot understand why so. Can some one help me out on this please.

Answer (score 0):

The part you've highlighted in the debugger is the *inner* exception. That isn't used by the CLR to determine which `catch` block to enter. The outer exception is just a `DbUpdateException` - which you haven't specified a particular catch block for.

Even the inner exception is just a `DataException`  - it's not an instance of your custom exception.

You haven't shown any code which actually *throws* your exception - are you sure it's being used at all? What code have you written to tell EF to throw your exception rather than the exception it would otherwise throw?

(Given your comments, I'm not sure you quite understand exception handling. Creating a custom exception doesn't somehow let you catch an instance of that without it being thrown - something still has to throw an instance of that exception before it's any use.)

Comment: Even i was not sure about this. Also what class should by custom exception class inherit from to catch all EF exceptions ?

Comment: I modified `CreateNewUserEntityFrameworkException : DbUpdateException` still the catch block is not catching this exception

Comment: @Yasser - You aren't throwing a CreateNewUserEntityFrameworkException.. so why would it catch one?

Comment: @Yasser: The question about "what class should my custom exception class inherit from to catch all EF exceptions" doesn't make sense, IMO.

Comment: Oh. so it seems my `_createUserModule.CreateUser` method should have a try catch with DbUpdateException in catch block and from there I should catch n throw my custom exception. Right ? Please correct me here if I may be wrong

Comment: @Yasser - I wouldn't say "that's what you SHOULD do", but If that's what you WANT to do, then yes... you should probably put the DbUpdateException in the InnerException of your custom exception.  However, doing that doesn't really make much sense to me.. but it's your code.

Comment: I am doing that so that only custom exceptions will be logged to elmah and it would be better to keep track of these exception as they will be having exception details in a format which will be easier to understand. IMO.